# wiringPi cleanup command

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I have some experience with the python GPIO library and am working on porting some of my code to C for better performance. Normally, at the end of programs, or when I break out of them with Ctrl-C, I have my code set up with a try except so that GPIO.cleanup() is called and my motors don't just keep on doing what they were doing when I broke out.

However, I see no equivalent of GPIO.cleanup() in wiringPi. Is there one, or do I not need to bother with this in wiringPi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware the only Python modules which have a cleanup function are RPi.GPIO and RPIO.GPIO. The others expect you to tidy up when you terminate.

None of the C libraries that I am aware off have an equivalent.  If you want to change the mode or level of a GPIO when your program terminates you have to explicitly do so yourself.

Comment: I tried this, but some of the pins I am using are the SPI pins. They are at the mode ALT0 by nature, and when I try a setMode(pin, ALT0) I get an error. Is there a way to set them back to the ALT0 state?

Comment: I don't know for wiringPi.  I'm afraid you'll need to check the documentation or look at the source code.  My pigpio is quite happy setting a GPIO to an ALT mode.  I.e. http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetMode (click on the mode parameter).  I think the bcm2835 C library also has a mode set command.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own "cleanup" code.  I don't know what kind of circuit / motors you are using, so I can only assume here.

If your motors are not running when the pi boots up, before your program runs, I would explicitly change the mode of all GPIO pins you touched back to inputs.  This will turn off your motors.