# GPIO LED not turning on

Tags: gpio, python

This is the code I used to test the LEDS on the GPIO. Every single LED worked, but the last LED, 4, wouldnt turn on. I have checked the wiring, The LED works, I even made sure the indents were in place.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(4, 1)
```

Comment: please fix the source formatting. 
python is very picky about the indentation 
also try enabling the warnings. there might be some useful messages that could help identify the problem

Comment: gpio:7: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:8: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:9: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)

Comment: gpio:10: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:11: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:12: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

Comment: gpio:13: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:14: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:15: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)

Comment: gpio:16: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:17: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
gpio:18: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)

Comment: These are all the warnings I get. I don't see #4 in there anywhere.

Comment: @Sailormanenzo You should add additional information to your question (using the edit button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hardware check

- make sure you have connected the led to right pin (many have been confused  with the BCM mode vs Board mode of naming the pins) Below you can see BCM mode GPIO4 is actually Board mode pin 7

[image: Pinout]

- make sure you didn't reverse bias the LED the final circuit
- if you have a driver circuit check the driving transistor type pnp/npn and adjust the o/p (`GPIO.HIGH` or `GPIO.LOW`) accordingly
- try using the swapping the LEDs from pin 4 on another port pin - should help determine if the led is defective or the problem is with the circuit/software

## Software check

You can simplify/modify the above code like so

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

channels = [4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25]

GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.cleanup(channels)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(channels, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
```

- add the `GPIO.cleanup` and use `GPIO.HIGH` as per the example [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/)
- try running as super user (like `sudo python .\led.py`)
- share the circuit diagram

HTH

After looking further into the warning i am suspecting
one or more pins are being used in their alternate functions mode

```
GPIO4  - none
GPIO7  - spi 0 chip en 1
GPIO8  - spi 0 chip en 0
GPIO9  - spi 0 miso
GPIO10 - spi 0 mosi
GPIO14 - uart 0 tx
GPIO15 - uart 0 rx
GPIO17 - none
GPIO18 - pcm clock
GPIO22 - none
GPIO23 - none
GPIO24 - none
GPIO25 - none
```

Assuming you dont have any other applications that use the SPI interface or the PCM clock,
I think the pins GPIO14(usart tx) and GPIO15(usart rx) causing the warnings.
Can you try the instructions [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection#S.2FW:_Preventing_Linux_from_using_the_serial_port) 
and disable the serial console and check if you still get warnings. If it does, it could collaterally fix your GPIO behavior too.

Just noticed you are missing [`GPIO.cleanup()`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34370/33810) which is required for clean exit.

Comment: GPIO4 Works now. However, there is a slight problem. When I try and light up two leds at the same time, only 1 turns on at a time. For example:           GPIO.output(4,  GPIO.HIGH) then GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)     First #4 turns on then off, and right after that #7 turns on.

Comment: @Sailormanenzo try this `GPIO.output([4, 7], GPIO.HIGH)`

Comment: @Sailormanenzo, if an answer worked for you, it would nice to accept it by clicking the tick mark near it.

Comment: Thanks but, the circuit im working on requires that if different values are inputed, different light turn on.

Comment: @Sailormanenzo try this
`leds = [] # create a empty list
 if <condition1>:
    leds.append(<pin#>)
# more conditions, add to the list as necessary and finally
GPIO.output(leds, GPIO.HIGH)
`
Also you might want to read up a bit of [python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm) if your are not already familiar

Comment: When I run the following, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yhlOtEAcI4qCAzRam4hT5H3xgvQAonHG_k7QaJX2vVk/edit?usp=sharing                   I get: weather-test.py:8: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(channels, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather-test.py", line 12, in <module>
    temperature = int(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature'])
KeyError: 'current_conditions'

Comment: I noticed couple of issues 
[1] the GPIO's seem to be in use (same as before)
[2] the error is due to the weather data not containing the key (current_conditions). i have updated your script to include a print to see what exactly your are getting from the webapi