# Circuitpython: ValueError: GP0 in use. How to reset GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, pi-pico, circuitpython

### Error Message

After having written a function that sets output and values to specific GPIO pins, I'm running into the following error:

> ValueError: GP0 in use.

### Code

The function is:

```
def detect_connection_between_two_pins_circuitpython(left, right):
    # Import for circuitpython.
    import board 
    import digitalio  
    
    left_pin=get_circuitpython_gpio_pin(board,left)
    right_pin=get_circuitpython_gpio_pin(board,right)
    # Set the output pin to GPIO pin nr 0.
    output_line = digitalio.DigitalInOut(left_pin)
    output_line.direction=digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

    # Set the input pin to GPIO pin nr 1.
    input_line = digitalio.DigitalInOut(right_pin)
    input_line.direction=digitalio.Direction.INPUT

    # Put voltage/value of 1 [-] on GPIO pin 0.
    output_line.value = 1

    if input_line.value == 1:
        #output_line.direction=None
        output_line=None
        #input_line.direction=None
        input_line=None
        return True
    # print(f"{left},{right}")
    #output_line.direction=None
    output_line=None
    #input_line.direction=None
    input_line=None
    return False
```

And for completeness, it uses the following mapping:

```
def get_circuitpython_gpio_pin(board,gpio_pin_nr):
    circuitpython_gpio_pins= [
        board.GP0,
        board.GP1,
        board.GP2, 
        board.GP3, 
        board.GP4, 
        board.GP5, 
        board.GP6, 
        board.GP7, 
        board.GP8, 
        board.GP9,
        board.GP10, 
        board.GP11, 
        board.GP12, 
        board.GP13,
        board.GP14, 
        board.GP15, 
        board.GP16, 
        board.GP17, 
        board.GP18, 
        board.GP19, 
        board.GP20, 
        board.GP21,
        board.GP22, 
        board.GP23, 
        board.GP24, 
        board.GP25, 
        board.GP26, 
        board.GP27, 
        board.GP28,
    ]
    return circuitpython_gpio_pins[gpio_pin_nr]
```

### Bug Interpretation

The error occurs the second time the function is called, at:

```
output_line = digitalio.DigitalInOut(left_pin)
```

Where it tries to set the value of GPIO pin `0`/`board.GP0` again. It seems to me it still has some value left from the previous time the function was called. So I tried resetting the GPIO pin `0` with:

```
#output_line.direction=None
output_line=None
#input_line.direction=None
input_line=None
```

However, `None` is not a valid direction, and setting the object to `None` does not alleviate the error.

### Question

How can I reset the value of the GPIO pin at the end of the function such that I can keep on calling the function (on the same pins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be asking for the Raspberry Pico equivalent of the `cleanup()` function that is discussed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/why-cleanup-the-gpio-pins) for the Raspberry Pi.

After looking at the objects that were used such as `digitalio` and `board.GP0` I found the `deinit()` function. This allows one to re-use the GPIO pins in the same script.

### Code

A working function was hence found with:

```
def detect_connection_between_two_pins_circuitpythonV5(left, right,circuitpython_pins):
    left_boardpin=pin_to_board_pin(left)
    right_boardpin=pin_to_board_pin(right)
    out = digitalio.DigitalInOut(left_boardpin)
    out.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
    out.value=1
    
    input = digitalio.DigitalInOut(right_boardpin)
    input.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
    input.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN

    # Check if the input has an incoming value.
    if input.value:
        out.deinit()
        input.deinit()
        return True
    #row.value = 0
    out.deinit()
    input.deinit()
    return False
```

and for completeness:

```
def pin_to_board_pin(pin_nr):
    if pin_nr==0:
        return board.GP0
    elif pin_nr==1:
        return board.GP1
    elif pin_nr==2:
        return board.GP2
    elif pin_nr==3:
        return board.GP3
    elif pin_nr==4:
        return board.GP4
    elif pin_nr==5:
        return board.GP5
    elif pin_nr==6:
        return board.GP6
    elif pin_nr==7:
        return board.GP7
    elif pin_nr==8:
        return board.GP8
    elif pin_nr==9:
        return board.GP9
    elif pin_nr==10:
        return board.GP10
    elif pin_nr==11:
        return board.GP11
    elif pin_nr==12:
        return board.GP12
    elif pin_nr==13:
        return board.GP13
    elif pin_nr==14:
        return board.GP14
    elif pin_nr==15:
        return board.GP15
    elif pin_nr==16:
        return board.GP16
    elif pin_nr==17:
        return board.GP17
    elif pin_nr==18:
        return board.GP18
    elif pin_nr==19:
        return board.GP19
    elif pin_nr==20:
        return board.GP20
    elif pin_nr==21:
        return board.GP21
    elif pin_nr==22:
        return board.GP22
    elif pin_nr==23:
        return board.GP23
    elif pin_nr==24:
        return board.GP24
    elif pin_nr==25:
        return board.GP25
    elif pin_nr==26:
        return board.GP26
    elif pin_nr==27:
        return board.GP27
    elif pin_nr==28:
        return board.GP28
    else:
        raise Exception(f"No  pin found for: pin_nr={pin_nr}.")
```